# Limit TranslationModes (copy/translate) in TYPO3 7 Translation Wizard

Tags: typo3-7.6.x

TYPO3 7 has a nice Translation Wizard where you have for each page the choice whether you translate the elements or copy them. Once you choose one mode its locked for this page (as long as there is a translated content element).

My question is: can I force one option (for redactor) that he can only make "real" translations and no copies.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A quick and dirty hack is to hide the unwanted option via CSS in the backend.
See https://forge.typo3.org/issues/76910

Comment: Thanks! I did that already - but forgot to answer here :-) So I accept your answer for now - for its the only solution so far.

Comment: With Version 9.0 the localization actions "Translate" and "Copy" are now toggleable by PageTS and UserTS: `mod.web_layout.localization.enableCopy = 1` and `mod.web_layout.localization.enableTranslate = 1`. See https://docs.typo3.org/typo3cms/extensions/core/latest/Changelog/9.0/Feature-76910-PageLayoutViewAllowToDisableCopyTranslateButtons.html